# Retrieve Flask JSON object with Javascript in HTML template

Tags: javascript, python, html, json, flask

I am using Flask to build a web app that displays a list of information to a user, and then allows them to do a find-and-replace type operation on the list, and finally export it as a csv.

I can display the information without JSON and JavaScript, but the data will not be persistently displayed throughout the find-and-replace operation (also, sending an API request every time a user clicks will be very expensive). So, I am trying to pass the list to a JavaScript var and hold it there for it then to be utilized and displayed appropriately in the HTML.

My Flask:

```
@app.route("/page", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def page():

list4 = ["test", "big", "test2"]

return render_template('page.html', title="page", list5=jsonify(list4))
```

My template:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div class="content-section">
</div>
<article class="media content-section">
        <div class="media-body">
          <div class="article-metadata">
            <a class="mr-2" href="#"></a>
            <small class="text-muted"></small>
          </div>
          <h2><a class="article-title" href="#"></a></h2>
          <p class="article-content">{{counts}}</p>
        </div>
</article>

</div>
{% endblock content %}

<script> var counts = {{ list5|tojson }}; </script>
```

When I run this,`counts` does not display anywhere on the page. Because I get no error (and especially because I am new to JSON and Flask), I am finding it difficult to debug.

My question is, how can I get `list4` to persistently display on my page in such a way that that a user can alter it without making API calls every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the [`jsonify`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.json.jsonify) function will return a `Response` object, so instead use `json.dumps(list4)` in your `return`. You also won't need to use `|tojson` in your template.

And to answer your question, to output the `list4` onto the template just replace `{{counts}}` with the json you've passed into the `render_template`, so `{{ list5 }}`.

To hold this in a javascript variable for client side manipulation, you can do the same thing and set the javascript variable to the JSON from the route:

```
<script>

var counts = {{ list5 }};

</script>
```

Comment: So if I refresh the page it's not making calls to the API each time? It's being held locally and I can use a script to implement a find-and-replace functionality on it?

Comment: When you refresh the page, yes it will make a request to the server for the page you're loading. Can you elaborate what you mean by the script? Is it a javascript script, or python that you are wanting to use?

Comment: I want to essentially hold it in the HTML template so I can manipulate it with a find-and-replace functionality. For example, when a user has their list printed out, I want them to be able to remove strings from the list. That can't be done effectively in Flask, so I want to pass the list from my Python code to a locally held Javascript var (as I showed in that second set of code at the bottom in the <script> tags), that way I can manipulate it and have it update the list dynamically for the user. So while you did allow me to print the list, I still can't convert it into Javascript. Thanks.

Comment: I see, I've updated my answer, but it's basically what you have already!

Comment: Thank you Dylan, I am going to accept your answer. I think my problem was that I was I had written my <script> tags outside of their proper scope. Thank you for the json dumps information, it is working.